# Porque meu .svg não funciona no Firefox?

Tags: html5, css3, svg

Meu .svg não é carregado no Firefox, no chrome ele funciona normal. Estou usando css para fazer isso, com a propriedade `background: url('data:image/svg+xml...)`.
Fiz um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thayllor/x0te1kyz/1/) para exemplificar, contendo todo o código.

**Edit:**
Não quero utilizar base64.

Comment: Eu tive esse mesmo problema agora em um projeto que faço parte. Eu estava definindo uma largura no css em porcentagem(%) e o firefox estava vendo como uma imagem sem dimensão. Alterei de porcentagem para um valor em "rem" e funcionou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Firefox interpreta o caratére # como um [Fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Para resolver substitua todos os `#` dentro da função URL por `%23`.

No seu caso você deve substituir:

- `<path fill="#1e7bbf"...` por `<path fill="%231e7bbf"...`
- `<text fill="#666"` por `<text fill="%23666"`

Veja o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd9fov5z/) corrigido.

```css
.modalFrame {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 550px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg version="1.1" width="450" height="100" margin="20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 250 100" enable-background="new 0 0 0 0" xml:space="preserve"> <path fill="%231e7bbf" d="M73,50c0-12.7-10.3-23-23-23S27,37.3,27,50 M30.9,50c0-10.5,8.5-19.1,19.1-19.1S69.1,39.5,69.1,50"> <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="1s" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" /> </path><text fill="%23666" x="40%" y="60%" font-family="\'Lucida Grande\', sans-serif" font-size="24">Carregando</text> </svg>') 0px 0px no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="modalFrame"></div>
```

fonte: [SVG data image not working on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733607/svg-data-image-not-working-on-firefox)

Comment: Entendi, valeu pela ajuda amigo!

Comment: Na verdade se o teu doctype estiver com charset utf-8, ou se vc disser no seu CSS @charset "UTF-8"; creio que não necessitará trocar isso manualmente, ele automaticamente interpretará o `#` para `%23`.

Answer (score 5):

Seu problema é por causa do " `#` " na cor do `fill`!

> [Deprecation] Using unescaped '#' characters in a data URI body is
>   deprecated and will be removed in M68, around July 2018. Please use
>   '%23' instead. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720 for more
>   details.

Se vc substituir o valor das cores por uma "*string*" tipo `red` ou `black` que vai funcionar ou trocar `#` por `%23` como sugerido pelo próprio *warning* acima. As versões antigas do Chrome dão esse alerte, apesar de conseguir renderizar a cor, mas parece que o FireFox mais antigo nem a cor chega a mostrar.

Pode testar aqui que pelo nos nos FireFox mais novo vai rodar.

```css
.modalFrame {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg version="1.1" width="450" height="100" margin="20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 250 100"> <path fill="red" d="M73,50c0-12.7-10.3-23-23-23S27,37.3,27,50 M30.9,50c0-10.5,8.5-19.1,19.1-19.1S69.1,39.5,69.1,50"> <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="1s" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" /> </path><text fill="darkgray" x="40%" y="60%" font-family="\'Lucida Grande\', sans-serif" font-size="24">Carregando</text> </svg>') 0px 0px no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="modalFrame"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante

Comment: @GilthayllorSousa dmr tmj